# How to get currently logged in username?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How do you get the currently logged in username in a Firemonkey Delphi project? I'm targeting both Windows and Mac.

I have XE2, but I suppose any version solution is fine because I will upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For Windows you can use the [`GetUserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPi function, for OSX you can use the `NSUserName` and/or `NSFullUserName` methods.

Try this sample for OSX

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Macapi.CoreFoundation,
  Macapi.Foundation,
  System.SysUtils;

function NSUserName: Pointer; cdecl; external '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation' name _PU +'NSUserName';
function NSFullUserName: Pointer; cdecl; external '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation' name _PU + 'NSFullUserName';

begin
  try
    Writeln(Format('User Name      %s',[TNSString.Wrap(NSUserName).UTF8String]));
    Writeln(Format('Full User Name %s',[TNSString.Wrap(NSFullUserName).UTF8String]))
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

For Windows

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

function WUserName: String;
var
  nSize: DWord;
begin
 nSize := 1024;
 SetLength(Result, nSize);
 if GetUserName(PChar(Result), nSize) then
   SetLength(Result, nSize-1)
 else
   RaiseLastOSError;
end;


begin
  try
   Writeln(WUserName);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Compiled into a single unit:

```
uses
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
  MacApi.CoreFoundation, MacApi.Foundation,
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Windows,
  {$ENDIF}
  System.SysUtils;

{$IFDEF MACOS}
function NSUserName: Pointer; cdecl; external '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation' name '_NSUserName';
{$ENDIF}

function GetUserName: String;
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
var
  nSize: DWord;
{$ENDIF}
begin
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
  Result := TNSString.Wrap(NSUserName).UTF8String;
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  nSize := 1024;
  SetLength(Result, nSize);
  if Windows.GetUserName(PChar(Result), nSize) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, nSize - 1)
  end
  else
  begin
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying this now. What's `_PU`?

Comment: _PU is just a constant for `_`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could add "missing" OS X functions like that.

Comment: For future use, I compiled your answer into a single function and added it to your answer. Not surprisingly, getting the computer name has a similar solution.

Comment: How would you define function NSUserName in Builder C++?

Answer (score 14):

Another simpler solution is to get the computer name via the environment variable using [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.GetEnvironmentVariable) function as follows:

```
Result := GetEnvironmentVariable('USERNAME');
```

P.S.This solution is for Windows and Linux but you need to check your Delphi source code if it is supported.

Comment: Fantastically simple (DXE3 & Win10), thanks. GetEnvironmentVariable gives so much info. +1.

Comment: ⚠ Just keep in mind users (and apps) can easily overwrite environment variables, so it's unsafe to limit/grant user access based solely on this value.

Comment: GetEnvironmentVariable looks like "SYSTEM". but it returns not logged in user name. but credentials user name which you run the executable. eg. it returns admin if you "run as admin" even you are in limited user account.

Comment: Any application can have environment variables - and it's just a memory block so can easily be changed.  It's NOT SAFE to assume that it is accurate (but I admit it's very easy to look at)

Answer (score 3):

A simpler answer for windows users

```
function CurrentUserName:String;  
var  
  UserName: array[0..127] of Char;  
  Size:DWord;  
begin  
  Size:=SizeOf(UserName);  
  GetUserName(UserName,Size);  
  Result:=UserName;  
end;
```

from [edn](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26731)