# How to get Full Name of current user in Delphi Win64

Tags: delphi

I've done a fair amount of searching and have found some useful tips [right here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599086/how-to-get-currently-logged-in-username) to get the Username and Computer name - and I've even [found some code](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=208622) posted by Norrit on Delphipages doing exactly what I need it to do - except that when running it under a Win64 Target Platform, obtaining the Full Name doesn't work - it returns an empty string.  It returns the full name fine when running a Win32 build.

The GetCurrentUser and GetDomainServerName functions work in both Win32 and Win64.

Doing Google searches for "delphi netusergetinfo" brings up a lot of results which are more than 10 years old - even before Delphi had Win64.  It also brings up an Experts-Exchange answer which links to some lanman example code which 404's on me, so I'm a bit stuck there.

Does anybody know what changes I have to make to get GetDomainFullName to work under Win64 - or does anybody have alternate code I can use to obtain the Full Name of the currently logged on user?

Full code shown below in case of link rot.

```
unit NetAPI32;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

  function GetCurrentUser(): String;
  function GetDomainServerName(): String;
  function GetDomainFullName(ServerName, UserName: String): String;

implementation

  function NetUserGetInfo(ServerName, UserName: PWideChar; Level: DWORD; var Buffer: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall; external 'netapi32.dll' name 'NetUserGetInfo';
  function NetApiBufferFree(Buffer: pointer): DWORD; stdcall; external 'netapi32.dll' name 'NetApiBufferFree';
  function NetWkstaUserGetInfo(ServerName: PWideChar; Level: DWORD; var Buffer: Pointer): Longint; stdcall; external 'netapi32.dll' name 'NetWkstaUserGetInfo';

type
  TUserInfo1 = packed record
    UserName: PWideChar;
    DomainName : PWideChar;
    OtherDomainNames: PWideChar;
    ServerName: PWideChar;
  end;
  PUserInfo1 = ^TUserInfo1;

  TUserInfo2 = packed record
    Name: PWideChar;
    Password: PWideChar;
    PasswordAge: DWORD;
    Priv: DWORD;
    HomeDir: PWideChar;
    Comment: PWideChar;
    Flags: DWORD;
    ScriptPath: PWideChar;
    AuthorFlags: DWORD;
    FullName: PWideChar;
    UserComment: PWideChar;
    Params: PWideChar;
    WorkStations: PWideChar;
    LastLogon: DWORD;
    LastLogoff: DWORD;
    AccountExpires: DWORD;
    MaxStorage: DWORD;
    UnitsPerWeek: DWORD;
    LogonHours: DWORD;
    BadPasswordCount: DWORD;
    LogonCount: DWORD;
    Server: PWideChar;
    CountryCode: DWORD;
    Codepage: DWORD;
  end;
  PUserInfo2 = ^TUserInfo2;

function GetCurrentUser(): String;
var
  username: String;
  size: DWORD;
begin
  size := 255;
  SetLength(username, size) ;
  if GetUserName(PChar(username), size) then
    Result := Copy(username, 1, size - 1)
  else
    Result := '';
end;

function GetDomainServerName(): String;
var
  PUI1: PUserInfo1;
begin
  Result := '';
  if NetWkstaUserGetInfo(nil, 1, Pointer(PUI1)) = 0 then
  begin
    try
      Result := WideCharToString(PUI1^.ServerName);
    finally
      NetApiBufferFree(PUI1);
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetDomainFullName(ServerName, UserName: String): String;
var
  PUI2: PUserInfo2;
begin
  Result := '';
  if NetUserGetInfo(PWideChar(WideString(ServerName)), PWideChar(WideString(UserName)), 2, Pointer(PUI2)) = 0 then
    try
      Result := WideString(PUI2^.FullName);
    finally
      NetApiBufferFree(PUI2);
    end;
end;

end.
```

Example of how to use:

```
ShowMessage(GetDomainFullName(GetDomainServerName(), GetCurrentUser()));
```

Delphi XE6 running on Windows 2012 R2

Comment: Use [System.SysUtils.Win32Check](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.Win32Check) to get the reason why the api call fails

Comment: `.LogonHours` must be `PByte` as per [`USER_INFO_2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_info_2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of `packed` is wrong, and has always been wrong. You just got away with it because it so happened that the layout on 32 bit is the same packed as aligned.

Remove the `packed` modifier from the struct declarations and your code will work.

Since you've moved to Unicode Delphi, you can stop using `WideString` now.

```
function GetDomainFullName(const ServerName, UserName: string): string;
var
  PUI2: PUserInfo2;
begin
  if NetUserGetInfo(PChar(ServerName), PChar(UserName), 2, Pointer(PUI2)) = 0 then
    try
      Result := PUI2^.FullName;
    finally
      NetApiBufferFree(PUI2);
    end
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

Comment: Indeed, removing "packed" from my unit fixed the issue :)  Thanks kindly.