# How to get the full windows user name

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-11

I got a local account that got a username "rabi"
when I execute
"whoami /all" I get some information about that user:
uname
mikeschleppi\rabatscher   ....
enumerates all groups and some priviledges. But also not all information that I want....

Some of that info I can query by using the
[GetUsernameEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms885647(v=msdn.10))
API.
Nevertheless the User Account Manager shows me a nice display name (like: John Doe)
and the email address that was used.

How can I get that information (especially full name) in Delphi? GetUsernameEx is obviously not the option here...

To clarify: The account window to manage my user account actually shows my full name
[image]

So I wondered how to get that information. I'm sure the code you guys suggested works for AD (and maybe even LDAP servers) but I'm interested in the information about the local user...

Comment: See [How to get Full Name of current user in Delphi Win64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25653117/4299358) from 8 years ago using [`NetUserGetInfo( USER_INFO_2 )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetinfo).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with ADSI. Here's a simple example:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ComObj,
  ActiveX,
  ActiveDs_TLB in 'ActiveDs_TLB.pas';

function ADsGetObject(lpszPathName: PChar; const riid: TGUID; out Obj): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'activeds.dll';

function GetADsUser(const Domain, Username: string): IADsUser;
var
  Path: string;
begin
  Path := 'WinNT://' + Domain + '/' + Username;
  OleCheck(ADsGetObject(PChar(Path), IID_IADsUser, Result));
end;

procedure Main;
var
  User: IADsUser;
begin
  User := GetADsUser('yourdomain', 'yourusername');
  Writeln(User.FullName);
  Writeln(User.EmailAddress);
end;

begin
  try
    OleCheck(CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED));
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

I obtained the TLB unit for ADSI using Embarcadero's `tlibimp` tool:

```
C:\Desktop>tlibimp -p C:\Windows\System32\activeds.tlb
Embarcadero TLIBIMP Version 12.16581
Copyright(c) 1995-2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.

Opening  C:\Windows\System32\activeds.tlb
Type library loaded ....
Created  C:\Desktop\ActiveDs_TLB.dcr
Created  C:\Desktop\ActiveDs_TLB.pas
```

Comment: Does it works when there is no Active Directory?

Comment: Many thanks - this is a great example! I'm sure it works on AD servers but I'm acutally interested in the local account (e.g. my computer is not connected to a domain...).